# What's the difference between Mountain Hardwear's Trango and AC lines of tents?

Tags: mountaineering, tents, winter-camping

Mountain Hardwear presently lists two major lines of [mountaineering tents](https://www.mountainhardwear.com/expedition-tents/): the Trango series and the AC series.  The primary difference seems to be that the Trangos feature a double-wall, are cheaper, and heavier, while the ACs feature a single-wall construction, are more expensive, and are lighter.

Is there more to it than this?  What are the target consumers for each line, and what is the best use for each product?  Does it really just boil down to a trade-off between price and weight?  Are there significant performance differences aside from weight?  For example, is one or the other thought to be considerably stronger in high wind, or more waterproof in very damp conditions?

Comment: The price difference seems to be marginal – Trango2 $700 / AC2 $650. Trango3 $820 / AC3 $900. One is a bit cheaper, the other a bit more. The website states about the AC range *"An ultralight mountaineering tent engineered for high-speed, high-altitude ascents where every gram counts ... sets up quickly and safely even in the harshest conditions."*

Comment: double wall is usually heavier, for obvious reasons. It would make sense to separate single wall and double wall into 2 separate lines of products. It's up to you to know if you want a single or a double wall tent

Answer (score 1):

The Trango is a basecamping tent- large, heavy (twice the weight of the AC), it focuses on having lots of space inside to hang out in, to cook in. It's got lots of tie outs, you spend a bunch of time setting it up nicely. You'll want the Trango if you're getting to altitude then peakbagging.

The AC is the light, summit push tent. It isn't as warm, but it's quicker to set up. You want to make sure you're setting it up in line with the likely direction of the wind. You'll want the AC for more general use, fair-weather mountaineering, it's going to suffice if you need to hunker down for a few days, but not as comfortably.